# jQuery change function to each element

Tags: jquery, css, image, each

I'm trying to find the height of each image with a class of portfolio.Img, then apply it to a sibling div with a class of `.overlay`. And if that height is less than 500, display none two children of overlay with an id of page_categories and a class of `.entry`.

This works but only for one image not all images on the page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {   
  $('img.portfolioImg').load(function() {
    var imgHeight = $('img.portfolioImg').height();
    $('.overlay').css('height', imgHeight - 40 + 'px');
    if ( $('.overlay').height() < 500 ) {
      $('#page_categories').css('display', 'none');
      $('.entry').css('display', 'none');
    }else{
    // do nothing
    }
  });
});
</script>
<div class="ct-coll-item col2 masonry-brick">
  <article>
    <img class="portfolioImg" src="_/img/13.png" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <div id="page_categories">
        <a href="#">Publication</a>, <a href="#">Typeface</a>
      </div>
      <h2><a href="#">Adam Howe Styles Men of Alaska for Port Magazine</a></h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>An experimental typographic project by Riccardo Sabatini, which is a typeface inspired by old mechanics technical drawings, the steampunk visual world, and modern machinery.</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="postmetadata">
        <time>July 23rd, 2012</time> / <a href="#">1 Comment</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

This `div.ct-coll-item` is repeated numerous times, I don't know how to apply `.each()` to make it work for all images and siblings/children.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want this:

```
$('img.portfolioImg').bind('load',function() {
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();
    var $overlay = $(this).siblings('.overlay');
    $overlay.css('height', imgHeight - 40 + 'px');
    if ( $overlay.height() < 500 ) {
        $('#page_categories',$overlay).css('display', 'none');
        //                    ^---------- selector context
        $('.entry',$overlay).css('display', 'none');
        //            ^---------- selector context
    }else{
    // do nothing
    }
});
```

<sub>[`.load()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)</sub>

Comment: I think this is right, but there are multiple instances of img.portfolioImg so they all end up with the same height?

Comment: @gilesadamthomas If your all images have same height at loading, then probably, yes. Check my code, and tell me the results.

Comment: Yes they do have the same height

Comment: not sure how selector context works but all the #page_categories and .entry seem to be hidden or visible dependant on the first overlay not their parent overlay height?

Comment: @gilesadamthomas  What's your markup strcture looks like `<article><img><div></div></article><article><img><div></div></article>` or `<article><img><div></div><img><div></div></article>`?

Comment: its in the desc above or <img></img><div class="overlay><div id="page_categories"></div><div class="entry"></div></div

Comment: @gilesadamthomas `$('#page_categories', context)` means only those `'#page_categories'` elements will be fetched, which are the descendants of `context` element. Same situation is with `$('.entry',$overlay)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change

```
$('img.portfolioImg').load(function() {
var imgHeight = $('img.portfolioImg').height();
```

to

```
$('img.portfolioImg').each(function(image) {
var imgHeight = $(this).height();
```

because `$('img.portfolioImg').height();` gives you the height of the first element

Comment: so it creates a variable for each instance of the img.portfolioImg?

Comment: yes, new var for each element in selection `$('img.portfolioImg')`
and `imgHeight` should be `$(this).height();`, not `$(image).height();` - fixed it in the ans